# Vite - empty assets folder (not whole outputDir)

Tags: build, config, vite

Due to other construction services e.g. from the CMS that is in use also puts files in the same folder as `outPutDir` I only need to empty the assets folder. At the same time, I want to keep the folder structure that comes by default by only specifying `outPutDir`

Is this possible with Vite?

I do not find anything about this in the documentation for Vite. However, this does not mean that it is not mentioned somewhere.

```
  build: {
    outDir: '../wwwroot/',
    emptyOutDir: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        chunkFileNames: 'assets/js/[name].[hash].js',
        entryFileNames: 'assets/js/[name].[hash].js',

        assetFileNames: ({name}) => {
          if (/\.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg)$/.test(name ?? '')) {
            return 'assets/images/[name].[hash][extname]';
          }

          if (/\.css$/.test(name ?? '')) {
            return 'assets/css/[name].[hash][extname]';
          }

          return 'assets/[name].[hash][extname]';
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

Comment: There's no such Vite config to do that. A simple workaround is to use a shell script to perform the custom deletions instead of `emptyOutDir`.

Comment: @tony19 That's what I thought, too, but I just had to ask if anyone had found a way to do it.

Answer (score 7):

In `vite.config.js` just create a Rollup plugin which deletes the assets folder in the `buildStart` hook:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { resolve } from 'path'
import { rm } from 'node:fs/promises'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [{
    name: "Cleaning assets folder",
    async buildStart() {
      await rm(resolve(__dirname, '../wwwroot/assets'), { recursive: true, force: true });
    }
  }],
  build: {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Documentation:

- https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#plugins
- https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#buildstart
- https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsrmpath-options-callback

Answer (score 0):

The solution in my case is to reroute where the CMS pick up the assets files from the frontend build.

It does not solve my original challenge but it solves my problem.

```
  build: {
    outDir: '../wwwroot/public/',
    sourcemap: true,
    manifest: true,
    reportCompressedSize: true,
    emptyOutDir: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        chunkFileNames: 'js/[name].[hash].js',
        entryFileNames: 'js/[name].[hash].js',

        assetFileNames: ({ name }) => {
          if (/\.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg)$/.test(name ?? '')) {
            return 'images/[name].[hash][extname]';
          }

          if (/\.css$/.test(name ?? '')) {
            return 'css/[name].[hash][extname]';
          }

          return '[name].[hash][extname]';
        },
      },
    },
  },
```